Assign hidden field value in textbox onblur asp.net using server tag
Using the server tag, I must give the value of the hidden field to the javascript method in the textbox onblur event inline.
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMaxLen" runat="server" Value="10" />

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTargetForBelow6" runat="server" MaxLength="10"
                        onkeyup="return FnAlert(this,"+ <%# hdnMaxLen.Value %> +");"
                        CssClass="form-control" AutoCompleteType="None" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

It shows an error like
The server tag is not well formed.


Ok a few issues here.
First up, server-side expressions are to use the "=" sign, not the "#" (pound sign).
Next up, native server controls cannot use nor have server-side expressions!
You can most certainly use binding expressions say inside of a GridView, ListView, Repeater etc.
So, for a button row click, I might say do this in a GridView:
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    ItemStyle-Width="140px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdEdit" runat="server"
                            ImageUrl="~/Content/edit2.png"
                            Width="48px"
                            Height="40px"
                            OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                            Style="margin-left: 15px" 
                            HotelName='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'
                            PKID = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

So, note how I am able to freely add custom attributes to the button (or image button in this example). And then in code behind, I can thus go:
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim btn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer  ' Get current grid view row

    Debug.Print(btn.Attributes("HotelName"))
    Debug.Print(btn.Attributes("PKID"))

But, for such server-side controls, I still can't use "<%= %>" expressions.
So, move such code to the server side.
Hence this:
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMaxLen" runat="server" Value="10" />

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTargetForBelow6" runat="server" MaxLength="10"

        CssClass="form-control" AutoCompleteType="None" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

        <script>

            function FnAlert(tbox, maxlen) {

                alert("Max len value passed = " + maxl)

            }

        </script>

And now in the page load event, you can add that client-side code.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTargetForBelow6.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", $"FnAlert(this,{hdnMaxLen.Value})");
    }

You probably could use a jQuery expression, but you can't add nor use server-side expressions for a server-side control - it not allowed, but in near all cases I can think of, it not an issue, since such code can be done server side against such server-side controls.
